# Specify Different MFA methods for User Groups In Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I'm Looking for a way to Specify Different MFA Methods for User Groups, when they Signing to a App.

Group1 - Users only to have MS Authenticator App verification.

Group2 - Users to have MS authenticator App and SMS Options as verification.

Is this possible to achieve in Azure AD? If so How?

Comment: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa

Comment: You can use conditional access to enforce MFA on a per-group basis.

Comment: Hello I referred this document and I have done the same to enforce MFA with Conditional access in my current set up, but my question is how to present users on above groups  only mentioned options? to eliminate users in Group 1 using SMS MFA